# How to Set Item Level Permission Using SharePoint Designer 2013 Work Flow?

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-online, permissions, workflow-manager

Currently i'm trying to create a workflow in SharePoint 2013 workflow platform   that sets item level permission, trying to set `read item level permission` to "XYZ" group in `SharePoint 2013 workflow`

i have achieved same [task](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html) in SharePoint 2010 workflow platform, now trying to create same  in 2013,

How to set item level permission?

Comment: also i have tryed [this](http://iswwwup.com/t/1fce5818a7fa/sharepoint-online-2013-workflow-to-change-file-permission-in-document-.html) and [this](http://www.codeexplain.com/code/394d29b5-37ee-40b1-91cd-1e4a3b62b27a)article also but not getting any solution

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding how you designed your workflow, any errors you receive and so on?

Comment: Unable to Break Role Inheritance and assign new permissions to an Current item from the Document Library.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the workflow to make it clearer?

Comment: Please find my BLOG  http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html
I had writte this blog after I accept the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple process of setting item level permission is not available for SharePoint 2013 workflows. The only way I was able to do was through REST api called under Appstep.

There are 2 calls made:

1. BreakRoleInheritance
2. AddRoleAssignment

[This blog](http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-%28Item-Level-Permissions%29)  by Yuri Leontyev​ ​ over at spssite.pro can be a good start.

Excerpt:

**BreakRoleInheritance​**

BreakRoleInheritance is just not documented and can be used using POST request:

```
https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)
```

where
           copyRoleAssignments – “if true, this method copies the role assignments of the parent securable object when breaking inheritance; otherwise, this method adds the current user to the permission level that is required to manage the list item.”
           clearSubscopes – “Indicates whether subscopes should be cleared or not.”

**AddRoleAssignment​​**

Instead of the Add there is AddRoleAssignment method that also can be called using POST request (NOTE: this method works incorrectly in RTM release of SharePoint 2013!!!! It checks user within current item and if user is  not found (usually as we’ve just broken inheritance) throws an exception.  In SharePoint Online and March CU it works as expected):

```
https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=20,roleDefId=1073741828)
```

where
          principalid is id of user or group within current site collection. You can get a list of users by executing using GET:

```
https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers
```

roleDefId is internal id of Role Definition (Read, Contribute, Full Control and so on). You can get a list of available role definitions using GET:

```
​https://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/roledefinitions​
```

Please [use this  guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx) to Enable App step in SharePoint 2013 Workflow, once you make sure all is set upped well the above solution will work fine.

facing some Error they are [image]

Comment: i have work on above article, but not getting any positive results...

Comment: working on [this articals](http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2014/08/31/conditionally-set-permissions-on-new-documents-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx) but not working for me

Comment: The same query works fine when called from jQuery ajax() from console, but not working in SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow and Rest API..

Comment: please call the api in app step and make sure workflow app permissions are enabled.

Comment: i have done same thing...

Comment: is the workflow app permission feature activated on your site collection and site?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Comment: yes workflow app permission feature activated on my site collection.           and i have also tried above article ,                                                            is " X-RequestDigest Header"  needed  for break inheritance ?

Comment: are you recieving any error? If possible can you put a screenshot of your workflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27513/discussion-between-i-touch-and-taran-goel).

Comment: i have added error screen shot in your answer

Comment: are you using on premise?
1) In Central Administration click on 'Manage web applications'

2) Select the web application you wish to add the Workflow Service Account to

3) Click the 'User Policy' button under the 'Policy' ribbon group.

4) Add your 'Workflow Service Account' and then choose the 'Full Read' permission.

Comment: The issue you have is workflow not having proper permissions as you are able to make the calls from browser meaning calls are correct

Comment: @I-touch you also might want to check your workflow has the right permissions by going to appinv.aspx page by following the steps in msdn link taran posted above.

Comment: Just chipping in that this is the method that I've been using on several projects a few months ago.  Works on both Office 365 and SP2013.  Also, appinv.aspx page creates an Add-in secrets that expire. If you register the add-in with AppRegNew.aspx, the secret expires in one year.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687469.aspx

Comment: @TaranGoel , i got my mistake , actually i'm  replacing contents on [This Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx) in * To grant full control permission to a workflow :-Step 7

Comment: @TaranGoel, i hvae link url string contains '%20' ,how to replace '%20' with 'space' in Workflow 2013

Comment: @I-touch..You should create a new question or explain a little further as I am not able to understand.

Comment: Please find my BLOG  http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html
I had writte this blog after I accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, This is possible in workflow using REST API. Below are the steps which you need to follow.

Step 1: Whatever REST you are writing that should be part of **App Step**.
[image]

[image]

Step 2:  As shown in screen shot you will have to write your commands in a workflow. There are some variables which you need to assign.

Step 3: Very first, you need to build dictionary where as variable name is **ContextHeaders** in aboveshown screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Step 4: Next need to set API url in very next line. That API url should be something like **https://YourSite/_api/contextinfo** and HTTP method should be HTTP Post.

Step 5: Next you need to set **Get** and that should be like **d/GetContextWebInformation/FormDigestValue**

Step 6: Again you need to build your dictionary for request headers to make REST call to break inheritance.

[image]
[image]

Step 7: Next you need to set variable to whom you want to give permissions after breaking the inheritance.
 In example shown above, we are assign some group ids to variable **userIds**.

Step 8: Write REST to break the inheritance. Your REST should look like
**https://YourSite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27YourListTitle%27)/items(%27[%Current Item:ID%]%27)/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=true)**. HTTP Request Type will be HTTP POST.

As we are breaking item level inheritance that's  why we are going with Current Item ID.

Step 9: You need to set variable **roleDefinition**. This role definition is for, what permission level you want to assign to particular user.group ID.

Step 10: For assigning unique permission to User/Group id, again you will have to make a REST call. your REST should look like **https://YourSite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27YoutListTitle%27)/items(%27[%Current Item:ID%]%27)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=[%Variable: Id%],roledefid=[%Variable: roleDefination%])**

This is how you can break inheritance and assign unique permissions.

I hope this will help you. Still, if you have any thing, please write back.

Answer (score 1):

I'd done this task with Designer workflow 2013 and REST API as follow reference sites -
[link](http://blog.bullseyeconsulting.com/archive/2014/08/31/conditionally-set-permissions-on-new-documents-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx)
[link2] (http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/)
Hope this should work for the same!!

Comment: Please find my BLOG  http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html
I had writte this blog after I accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using out of the box workflow actions you can't do it because of security limitations. As solution I would like to suggest to have a look at a [Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). It is extended set of workflow actions for SharePoint Designer which also contains a set of workflow actions for [permission management](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/permissions-management/#GrantPermissionOnItem).

I'm one of developers of the product and I'm proud of it, that's why I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API of SP2013 for this. The accepted answer fails to mention that you should of course provide your list item and not a list.

1) Break roleInheritance ([official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItemBreakRoleInheritance))

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitembyid(" + id + ")/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=false)"
```

2) Add role assignments ([official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_RoleAssignmentCollectionAddRoleAssignment))

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitembyid(" + id + ")/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=<user or group id>, roledefid=1073741827)"

    // roledefid for Permission Levels are as follows:
    // 1073741829, Full Control
    // 1073741827, Contribute
    // 1073741826, Read
```

The documentation shows you can perform addroleassignment to a web object, but again, provide your list item instead.

For the second request, I needed to add this to the headers:

```
"X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
```