# web service Item permission in workflow designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services

```
  https://[sitesname]/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(4)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=17,roledefid=1073741826)
```

I called the above web service in the Sharepoint Designer,
and I got the below response

> `{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}`

I have checked the running account for this workflow have a FULL CONTROL and Limited ACCESS  permission to this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limited access is not a permIssion which will give you read access. Moreover you are trying to put item level permIssion which in turn would require full control.
You should add full control to the item or you should call the web service in an app step

Comment: Add full control to the workflow executor or full control to the list item?

Comment: To the list item

Comment: the response code become :bad request.

Comment: what all steps are you following? You need to first break the permission and only then add roles!. please refer this:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-work-flow/153981#153981

Comment: yes, I have broken the role inheritance and then using the above assignment. But it is strange to have bad request error. I have added the web service into workflow app step.

Comment: did you enable workflow can use app permissions feature and registered in appinv ?