# SharePoint Library settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-library

I want to make a Team/Project site which should be accessible for all internal employees. The Document library should however, only be accessible to the initial folder/content creator on the site, and the people the person want to share the info with.

**My problem is -**

When I create a site, and invite everybody except external to the site. Add the doc-library and create a folder (with contributor permission), when that folder I created, everybody - except external has access to this folder and its content,

Is there a setting, where I can limit access to the creator of the folder? And this person can then add people as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove inherited permissions from the document library. On my site I created an all staff security group and then a group for each department/ team.

I gave the all staff group read permission to the main Team site. I then created a load of document libraries (per department) and the stripped the inherited permissions and allowed each department edit access to their own library but no one else's. Users then can only see and access the libraries you allow them to.

To stop permission inheritance, open up your document library, click on the COG wheel, Library settings and click on Permissions for this document library and click stop inheriting permissions. Then click on your groups/ or users and assign the permissions you want them to have to the document library e.g. read, edit etc. See link below for reference.

I hope this makes sense and helps?

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting which would enable you to create a Document Library/Folder which would by default have unique permissions. Therefore each time a new Document Library, Folder, or basically anything that needs to have a different permission setting than its parent has (whether it's a parent library, site, etc.), you need to change the Document Library's/Folder's settings so, that it has unique permissions.

However, there's a possibility to automatize the process by creating a workflow which breaks the permission inheritance and assigns unique permission to the item. If this sounds like a suitable solution for you, I advice you to have a look at this another answer existing here in SharePoint.SE: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/153981/21441.