# Change user permissions of item with REST api

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, rest

There is a list in which every item has unique permissions. I used [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-work-flow) very helpful topic, where it is described how to break inheritance and create unique permissions and after that to add permissions.

I did all fine and this works great, but I have to edit unique permissions, once some action happens in list. So I have to edit permissions of item again and to change from lets say Contribute to Read level to particular user.

Example:
Item has unique permissions and one user has contribute permissions, after one of column's value is changed, I have to remove his contribute permissions and give him only read or to remove his permissions at all.
I tried standard rest call

```
SiteURL/_api/web/lists(guid'GUID')/items(ID)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=userID,roleDefId=1073741826)
```

But all I get is that that user beside Contribute permissions get Read permissions. Contribute stay, they are not removed.

Any suggestion how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also call [removeroleassignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_RoleAssignmentCollectionRemoveRoleAssignment):

```
SiteURL/_api/web/lists(guid'GUID')/items(ID)/roleassignments/removeroleassignment(principalid=userID,roleDefId=1073741827)
```